# JxBrowser strategy for efficiently retrieving favicon

Tags: java, chromium, kotlin, jxbrowser

As far as I can tell there is no infrastructure for favicons in JxBrowser. Shouldn't the favicon be a part of the title event ? I'm thinking my best bet is to just go for `http://<domain>/favicon.ico` but this is going to be so much redundant work (http client and caching mechanism).

Is there any way I can use the JxBrowser to take care of this elegantly?

I've tried two strategies for trying to reliably get a hold of the resources, it's not reliable enough though:

Event based url acquisition (`ResourceType.FAVICON` is never seen):

```
browser.context.networkService.resourceHandler = object : ResourceHandler {
    override fun canLoadResource(p0: ResourceParams?): Boolean {
        if (p0!!.resourceType == ResourceType.FAVICON) println(p0!!.url)
        if (p0!!.resourceType == ResourceType.IMAGE && p0.url.contains("favicon")) println("found favicon url: ${p0.url}")
        return true
    }
}
```

// xpath based approach

```
browser.addLoadListener(object : LoadListener {
    override fun onDocumentLoadedInMainFrame(p0: LoadEvent) {
        p0.inSwingThread {
            val res = it.browser.document.findElements(By.xpath("//link[@rel=\"icon\" or @rel=\"shortcut icon\"]"))
            res.forEach {
                println("----------")
                it.attributes.forEach { println(it.key + " " + it.value) }
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to insert a line-break after the if conditionals in your first code block (I'm not familiar with the syntax so I didn't want to somehow break the code). On my computer the code following the second if conditional can't be seen unless you scroll right, making it seem as though you want to `return true` if that conditional is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now JxBrowser API doesn't provide functionality that allows downloading the `favicon.ico` file. I recommend that you use standard Java API and the approach with `http://<domain>/favicon.ico`. For example:

```
URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("D:/favicon.ico"));
for ( int i; (i = in.read()) != -1; ) {
    out.write(i);
}
in.close();
out.close();
```